# I keep getting an error for array.Select

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine

So I'm creating this planet world generation system and have run into an error.

It keeps saying `No overload for method 'Select' takes 5 arguments`. When I remove the int count part of the Range it gives me another error. I ported this from a javascript application I found online. Any help is appreciated!

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class WorldGeneration: MonoBehaviour {
    float tileX;
    float tileY;
    void Generate() {
        float offset = .01f;

        int resolution = 360;
        int radius = 100;
        int noiseHeight = 50;
        int circleX = 1000;
        int circleY = 1000;
        var TWO_PI = Math.PI*2;

        for(int i=0; i<resolution; i++) {

            float angle = Enumerable.Range(1, 1000).Select(i,0,resolution,0,TWO_PI);
            float circleOffX = (float)Math.Cos(angle+offset) * (radius+Mathf.PerlinNoise(i*0.1f,offset)*noiseHeight);
            float circleOffY = (float)Math.Sin(angle+offset) * (radius+Mathf.PerlinNoise(i*0.1f,offset)*noiseHeight);

            tileX = circleX + circleOffX;
            tileY = circleY + circleOffY;
        }

        var width = 0.16f;
        var height = 0.16f;

        var manager = GetComponent<TileManager>();
        var obj = manager.Generate(1);
        obj.transform.position = new Vector2(tileX * width, tileY *  height);
    }
}
```

If the original javascript code is needed:

```
float offset = 0;

void setup() {
    size(512,512);
    noStroke();
    fill(255);
}

void draw() {
    background(0);
    offset+= .01;

    int resolution = 360;
    int radius = 100;
    int noiseHeight = 50;
    int circleX = width/2;
    int circleY = height/2;

    beginShape();

    for(int i=0; i<resolution; i++) {

        float angle = map(i,0,resolution,0,TWO_PI);
        float circleOffX = cos(angle+offset) * (radius+noise(i*.1,offset)*noiseHeight);
        float circleOffY = sin(angle+offset) * (radius+noise(i*.1,offset)*noiseHeight);

        float x = circleX + circleOffX;
        float y = circleY + circleOffY;

        vertex(x,y);
    }
    endShape();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is telling you there is no `Select` function that take 5 parameters.

So `Select(i,0,resolution,0,TWO_PI)` is invalid in the following line of your code because it has 5 parameters (`i`, `0`, `resolution`, `0`, and `TWO_PI`)

```
float angle = Enumerable.Range(1, 1000).Select(i,0,resolution,0,TWO_PI);
```

Look at the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.110).aspx) for `Select` and find what parameters are available, and correct the call of `Select`.